# Marginal density plot for a categorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm looking to build a chart with marginal density plots on the periphery / axes. Is there an easy way to do this for categorical data?

I've tried doing this with ggExtra's ggMarginal function, which works well for numerical data, but (based on my understanding) not categorical data. For ease of reproducibility,  I am using the mtcars data set, and converting the Cylinders to factors.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=as.factor(cyl), color=mpg, size=mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position="none")

p1 <- ggMarginal(p, type="histogram", size=10)
```

Given 'cyl' is being passed as a factor, I get the error:

```
Error in zero_range(range) : x must be length 1 or 2
In addition: Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_bin()`:
x must be length 1 or 2
```

Is there a workaround I can use for ggMarginal? Alternatively, I'm open to using any other method too.

Look forward to your suggestions!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you specify margins="x", you get the "x" marginal plotted:

```
p1 <- ggMarginal(p, type="histogram", size=10, margins="x")
png(); print(p1); dev.off()
```

[image]

Admittedly not what you wanted, and I don't see a reason why a historgram marginal would not be easily feasible for a categorical variable. Perhaps you should ask the maintainer for an enhancement in the next release?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @42-. I will reach out to the maintainer. And yes, ggMarginal works well for numerical data.